# Sybase to Netezza - attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows

Tags: sql, sybase, migrate, netezza

im exporting procedures from sybase to netezza and in some of the procedures there is query that keeps giving me the "Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows"
Data and table structure on both databases is the same, and this query woks on Sybase but not on Netezza

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.column1=t2.column1
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.column2=t2.column2;
```

What could cause this error if data and query is the same ?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you have at least 1 row in table1 that joins too at least 2 rows in table 2, which causes confusion about which value should end up column1.

For example:

```
select * from table1;
 COLUMN1 | COLUMN2
---------+---------
       1 |       1
(1 row)

select * from table2;
 COLUMN1 | COLUMN2
---------+---------
       3 |       1
       2 |       1
(2 rows)


UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.column1=t2.column1
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.column2=t2.column2;

ERROR:  Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows
```

It's not clear whether column1 in table1 should be set to 2 or 3, so the error is given and the transaction is rolled back.

I can't speak to why sybase allows this, however.